# Why does a function have long-term write access to all of its in-out parameters?

Tags: swift, memory-safety

According to the chapter of "Memory Safety" in the Swift Programming Language Guide (for Swift 4.2), there is a sentence "A function has long-term write access to all of its in-out parameters."
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/MemorySafety.html

I created a new command line tool project to verify it in Xcode 10.1.

```
var stepSize = 1

func increment(_ number: inout Int) {
  print(stepSize)
}

increment(&stepSize)
```

I expect the output to be 1, but the actual output is a crash log "Simultaneous accesses to 0x100587430, but modification requires exclusive access."

I know this is a conflict about accessing in-out parameters, but I don't know why this happens. Why does a function have long-term write access to all of its in-out parameters?

Comment: _"The write access for an in-out parameter [...] lasts for the entire duration of that function call"_ Are you saying that you expect the write access to end before the function returns?

Comment: why is there a memory conflict in single thread swift ? i never heard of memory conflict in javascript

Comment: See discussion of memory exclusivity checking in WWDC 2018 [What’s New in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/401/?time=2027).

Answer (score 2):

A consumer of this API sees `func increment(_ number: inout Int)`, but not the implementation. It can only assume that `increment(_:)` makes writes to the parameters, because *it can*, in principle.

Even if the function implementation doesn't currently do any writes, the possibility is there, so the compiler has to assume the worst case scenario. Imagine if some client code was allowed to compile against this, treating is as if it's read only (because at the time, it may be the case). What should happen to the client code when someone adds `number += 1` to the function body?

This is similar to having a function that declares it can `throw`, whose actual implementation doesn't `throw`. The compiler still treats it as throwing, and necessitates the error be handled with some variant of `try`.